# Check if value is in array PHP (easy?)

Tags: php, arrays

I think I have a very easy question, but I am stuck anyway. I want to check if the value is in an array, and if it is, i want to change the variable value.

```
$admin_is_menu = "about";
$test = array();
$test = [
["Name" => "About","alias" => "about"],
["Name" => "Test", "alias" => "test"],
];
if(in_array($admin_is_menu, $test)){
    $admin_is_menu = "true";
}
echo $admin_is_menu;
```

In the code above, it should output the echo `"true"`, since `"about"` is in the array. But is unfortunally does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `in_array($admin_is_menu, array_column($test,'alias'))`

Comment: That still echoes `"about"`

Comment: funny, it echo'd "true" for me.

Comment: and seeing an answer posted using the same coding, @cske should be posting an answer for it, or at the very least; given some credit.

Comment: I think I am doing some small thing wrong yes, cske had the right answer indeed! Unfortunally i cannot upvote his post , nor an unposted answer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `array_column` to get all array value.

```
$admin_is_menu = "about";
$test = array();
$test = [
["Name" => "About","alias" => "about"],
["Name" => "Test", "alias" => "test"],
];
if(in_array($admin_is_menu, array_column($test,'alias'))){
    $admin_is_menu = "true";
}
echo $admin_is_menu;
```

[DEMO](http://phpio.net/s/fjz)

Answer (score 1):

@cske pointed out in the comment how to do it. Here's a small explanation for that as well.

You should use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php). In this case `array_column($test, "alias")` will return a new array:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "about"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
```

Now, you check within it with `in_array`:

```
in_array($admin_is_menu, array_column($test,'alias'))
```

and this will return `true`